# My attempt to construct transformation matrix using 3 vertices (didn't work, need help)

Tags: python

Smart people in the past offered a solution to construct transformation matrix using 3 vertices:

[How do I construct a transformation matrix from 3 vertices?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30808/how-do-i-construct-a-transformation-matrix-from-3-vertices)

I tried to test it but I could not get it right. Please see attached code, screenshot, and blender file.

I would like to align Suzanne origin to K and align Suzanne's y axis to the normal of the plane defined by (k, i, j). I don't need (i, j) beyond defining the plane. My problem is my code doesn't do it. And I couldn't figure out why.

Thanks!

[image: three random vertices]

[image: My goal: to align the monkey origin to "k"]

```
# https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30808/how-do-i-construct-a-transformation-matrix-from-3-vertices

import bpy
from mathutils import *

# randomly selected 3 vertices
i = Vector((0.778421, 0.112746, 1.402834))
j = Vector((1.444566, 0.088229, 2.944015))
k = Vector((1.476759, 0.047526, 1.439882))

# to visualized the points
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(size=0.05, location=i)
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(size=0.05, location=j)
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(size=0.05, location=k)

a = i - k
b = j - k
c = a.cross(b).normalized() #y axis?
d = c.cross(a).normalized() #z axis?
e = c.cross(d).normalized() #x axis?

m = Matrix.Translation(k) * Matrix.Scale(1,4) * Matrix((e, c, d)).transposed().to_4x4()

obj = bpy.data.objects['Suzanne']
obj.matrix_world = m*obj.matrix_world
```

[image]

Comment: So if I understand correctly: K-> origin location, KJ -> rotation around x-axis, KI-> rotaion around y and z-axis ?

Comment: Going by answer in [link above](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30809/15543), the three points make up a plane, the normal to the plane (`ik.cross(jk)`) is one axis, (both other axes lie on the plane) arbitrarily one of the vectors  ik, or jk is chosen as another axis, and the third is their cross product.  This will ensure the three axes are orthogonal.  If the matrix, created from axes,  is orthogonal its transpose is its inverse. (or use `matrix.is_orthogonal` to check)  You have to decide which two local axes of suzanne will be the planes normal,  and the other on the plane..

Comment: I would like to align Suzanne origin to K and align Suzanne's y axis to the normal of the plane defined by (k, i, j). I don't need (i, j) beyond defining the plane. My problem is the code above doesn't do it. And I couldn't figure out why.

Comment: Only thing I would change is last line to `obj.matrix_world = m` otherwise you only get result you are after when suzanne's matrix world is identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by batfinger in the comment. Just change the last line to

```
obj.matrix_wolrd = m
```

everything works well now. Thanks!